# Fast querying with gin index on table with column containing XML tags

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gwt-gin, tsvector

I have a very large knowledge base(Yago2) with columns that are of the form of XMl tags e.g. `'<Albert_Einstein>'`. Performance is very important in my use case so I created a gin index like that:

```
 create index col_idx on yagofacts using gin(to_tsvector('english', column_name));
```

Now I am trying to query it with

```
select * from yagofacts where to_tsvector('english', column_name) @@ to_tsquery('Albert_Einstein');
```

However, it doesn't return any result because it can't search in the XML tags. 
I saw one solution to a previous question where I could do:

```
select to_tsvector( 'simple', regexp_replace(column_name, E'[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', 'g')) @@ to_tsquery('simple','Albert_Einstein');
```

The problem is it doesn't have good performance because it doesn't make use of the gin index I created. How can I query it fast?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this, by creating a gin index on:

```
 create index no_xml_idx on yagofacts using gin(to_tsvector('simple', regexp_replace(column_name, E'[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', 'g')));
```